# Access Database Structure

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I am creating a db for my large club. Spouses may also belong. Trying to keep from entering "Address" more than once, I set the structure as follows:
tblMember: memberID, FirstName, LastName, etc.
tblAddress: addressID, Address, City, Home Phone

To create the relationship I can:

1. add a addressID field to tblMember and link it to tblAddress
2. or create a join table: memberID, addressID and treat the relationship as a many to many.

Which is the best option?
Many thank,
John

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want:
a) a member to be able to have more than one address
and
b) an address to house more than one member
only then should you have a many to many relation.

Otherwise your option no 1 is the one to use.